# How to do this with a Many-to-Many relation

Tags: sql, database-design

I have two objects  : channel and tag a with many-to-many relation. A channel can have multiple tags, and a tag can have multiple channels.

So I have three tables:
-channel table
-tag table
-junction table

On the channel page, there will be the list of the tags linked to it. I also want that if a user clicks on a tag, it increases a counter linked to it. 
But I'm not sure how to do that.

Can I add a third column on the junction table for the number of clicks ?
Or can I have duplicates in the junction table (i.e each time a user clicks on tag "kids" of channel "omega", it would add a line to the junction table linking id of "kids" and id "omega")

Or is there another/better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a counter column to the relationship. Don't store duplicate rows. If you want to track individual clicks, you could add a user_id and datetime column and make them part of the primary or unique key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually did want to track individual clicks so it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

You could store that clicks in different table. Simple as that. Adding multiple rows to existing tables will make it unreadable. And constantly updating on click is also not good idea. Just create another table with that clicks and store each. Later You can show them in view grouped and count them.